# collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath is not executed

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

Here is my image of collectionViewCell .

[image: cell Image]

I have `collectionView` inside `tableViewCell` and I have a button inside `collectionViewCell` which is working perfectly as my wish. But What is troubling me is the function `didSelectItemAt`  is not being called .

I tried with

```
mycollectionview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
mycollectionview.allowsSelection = true
```

but still not working . Is the button inside `collectionViewCell` is the cause behind it as I read somewhere . If its is so how can I fix the issue .

Comment: set appropriate button size

Comment: appropriate Button size means ?  i have set height and width for the button inside the collectionViewCell which is already there . Please explain bit more . Thank you

Comment: wha is size(Hight and width) of button?

Comment: Did set delegate for uicollectionview

Comment: please check cell Image at my question . I have button whose height and width are set . which button size you want me to set ?

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm that you have set the delegate for the `UICollectionView` to your ViewController not the `TableViewCell`. If you have set the Delegate to `UITableViewCell`, then your `didSelectItemAt` will be called inside the `TableViewCell's` class

Comment: can you please explain bit more . I have collectionView outlet at tableViewCell so I have set delegate and datasource inside the func awakeFromNib(){ datasource, delegate} . Thank you

Comment: where you want to call the function ? in viewController or TableView cell's class

Comment: if you want to call delegate in UIVIewController. in UITableView's cellForItemAtIndexPaht, set the delegate to self.    
cell.collectionView.delegate = self

Answer (score 1):

try this code in swift 4

`cell.btnCart.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnCartAction), for: .touchUpInside)`

and handle the action

```
@objc func btnCartAction(sender:UIButton) {
        //write your code here
}
```

Comment: yes the cartButton is working perfectly but I want to tap the cell and assign different action . but the problem is  function didSelectItemAt is not executed .

Answer (score 0):

Check your all views which are placed on cell.If they have user interaction enabled and if user interaction enabled then what is the size of that item. It looks like some view is covering the whole cell that's why did select item does not get called.

Comment: if still you can't find it then you can place a uibutton in background as per cell size and can attach another action to that button.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/md74fp .   here is my UI Element hierarchy . I have added a View for shadow purpose in collectionViewCell and added everything inside the View eg image , label and button .

Comment: View's user interaction is enabled?

Comment: Just try by disabling this view's interaction. If did select row is working. If this works then also you need to enable view's interaction so that elements inside view can take user interaction. So the solution is to place another big button as per cell size in background and in that action you can do whatever you were doing in did select row.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Your Button size ,tableView selection (single selection or Multiple), check tableView user Interaction is enable,  also check datasource or delegate is connected